# JOptionDialog display Stacks How to?

Tags: java, dialog, stack, message, joptionpane

Okay guys I need for this Lab is to display stacks that I made in JOptionMessageDialog box and I have no idea how to display the stack. I keep displaying @jkh24k54 instead of the set of integers.??

My code:

```
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lab5
{

  public static void main(String[] arg)
  {

Random rnd =  new Random();

Stack<Integer> stack = new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack0= new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack1= new IStack<Integer>();
Stack<Integer> stack2= new IStack<Integer>();
int stream;


for(int i=0;i<20;i++)
{
  stream = rnd.nextInt(101);
  stack.push(stream);
  stack2.push(stream);
}
while( !stack2.isEmpty())
{
  int x = stack2.pop();
  stack.push(x);
}

   for(int i=0; i<20; i++)
   {
     int x= stack.pop();

  if(x%3==0)
    stack0.push(x);
  if(x%3==1)
    stack1.push(x);
  if(x%3==2)
    stack2.push(x);
}

   while( !stack.isEmpty() )
      System.out.print(stack.pop()+" ");
    System.out.println();
    while( !stack0.isEmpty() )
      System.out.print(stack0.pop()+" ");
    System.out.println();
     while( !stack1.isEmpty() )
      System.out.print(stack1.pop()+" ");
    System.out.println();
     while( !stack2.isEmpty() )
      System.out.print(stack2.pop()+" ");
    System.out.println();

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Original stack: "+ stack.toString()+ "\n"+
                              " 0%3: "+stack0.toString()+"\n"+ "1%3: "+stack1.toString()+"\n"+ " 2%3: "+stack2.toString());
```

}
}

Comment: The last line is what I need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calling the default toString() method of an Object which prints its memory location by default that is why you are getting @jkh24k54.  You need to override the toString() method of your stack class to return a string of the elements in your array.

An example: add something like this to your Stack Class.

```
@Override
public String toString()
{
    String returnString = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < yourarray.length; i++)
    {
        if(yourarray[i] != null)
        {
            returnString += yourarray[i];
        }
        ////if you want to add spaces for null then add this
        else
        {
            returnString += " ";
        }
        ////the else is probably not necessary for what you are doing
    }
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't print the memory location per say; it prints out its hashcode, which in some cases (I think it's java8+) is the memory location.

Comment: How would I do that? 
I can't create an actual string in my code as per requirements of this lab.

Comment: Good enough, it works. He'll probbaly count off but I have work in 20 minutes. Only other question is when I do do this I get some numbers and the "null" for each empty slot in the array up to 20..is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Just don't add the elements to the returnString if it is == null.

Comment: Also can you upvote this and mark as correct.  He shouldn't count wrong because this is the correct way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: if(stack[i] == null)
           return;   ?

Comment: I am definitely going to mark as correct, it told me I had to wait 2 minutes. Thank You by the way!

Comment: Can you show me how to mark null as nothing in string?

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome - I edited my post basically just don't add yourarray[i] to the return string if it is null.  If you want blank spaces you could add " " if it is null.